# Applying column filters in DMS Task for source MongoDB and target Postgres

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms, aws-documentdb

In my AWS DMS Task Source - MongoDB Target - RDS Postgres SQL

I am able to apply column filter and only 3 selected columns get migrated to target.

But if the source mongo document contains an object datatype. So In the Include-column filter after specifying

- oid__id
- phone_no
- address
- Params.name
- Params.age

Only the top two columns oid__id, address, and phone_no get migrated to target and the remaining two columns are skipped by the DMS task.

Comment: Do you have logging enabled on the DMS task and if so, raise the level to Debug? Check if there's any indication on why those fields are not replicated.

Comment: I was able to solve it, in the mongo source endpoint I increased docsToInvestigate from 1000 to 10000. As earlier mongo collection first 1000 docs doesn't had those two parameters.